# Try Ubuntu from disk

Tags: installation

Downloaded Ubuntu and burned ISO disk.  I have a desktop and laptop computer, both with Windows XP SP3.  I wanted to try running Ubuntu from the disk.  On the desktop I get past the screen where I select English.  It starts to present the Ubuntu wallpaper then goes to a screen with a pixelated orangish screen and stops loading.  Tried to on my laptop.  Get past the language screen and get an error message and have to close Ubuntu.  Have tried to run it on both computers several times and get the same problems each time.  Any way to get this to run without installing it on the computer?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Can you confirm you are booting from CD-ROM or running this from the Windows Desktop?   (It sounds like you are describing the latter.  If so consider booting from the CD-ROM drive and try the live Disk option,  this will allow you to try Ubuntu with out installing it also).  If this also renders the same result it indicate the the burn of the ISO image to disk is corrupt.   You can perform an MD5SUM check to confirm the image is OK..  I found a site that can help you.  Windows support available.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 0):

For a full Ubuntu experience without installing it on HDD I would recommend creating a bootable USB stick or disk. To do it on Windows you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), it is pretty straightforward.